# AWS: clear cache files for Pycharm in AWS workspace

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cache-control

I am developing a dashboard by using Python Dash plotly inside AWS workspace.

Then my Pycharm IDE became very slow and then it could not be re-opened.

I think its because of cache.

After I input 'df -h' in terminal, this is what I got

[image]

Anyone can advise how to clear the cache ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder under your name and empty core files, tmp file and other cache files, then you will have more space.